# Angular send form status data between components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

In my Angular application I have a component with a Submit button than sends information to a API that the user has entered, The Text Area where the user enters the Data is in a seperate component with a Validator. Is it possible to disable the submit button using the '[disabled]' attribute if the form inside a different isnt valid

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">

<textarea
    formControlName="jsonField" 
         cols="800" 
         rows = '18'
         style="width:1000px"
         spellcheck="false"
         placeholder="my custom json here">

</textarea>
```

Here is the Other Component with the Submit button

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="emailSearchForm.status == 'INVALID'"  
                class="item-submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: It’s unclear how this is structured. Do you have one component with a form and a second component that contains the textarea? Point is really, in the parent component, do you have 2 formGroups?

Comment: Sorry man, One Component with the Form and Text Area, another component with the Submit button but it does contains other forms, But I what I want is the validation from a form in component 1 to change the Submit button in component 2, Thanks for replying man (:

Comment: So... okay... still not fully clear :-). So how do you submit this form that is composed from mulitple components and forms..? Because you should already have something that has access to everything... right?

Comment: you can send form as an @Input() to component that holds the button and do [disabled]="emailSearchForm.invalid" if component that holds form is parent to the one that holds button. otherwise pls see sibling component interaction

Comment: So the ‘correct’ way is to use either custom (controlValueAccesor) form components or use sub-forms to build an ‘uber form’ from smaller elements. This has - at the top level - a formgroup that ties everything together - including valid states that you can use to enable / disable what you want..

Comment: @MikeOne Hey man, I use the valueChanges.subscribe method to detect any changes the user makes to the text area, then emit that value to the other component then store it inside a variable which can then be sent to the API,

Comment: Sure. But that is a pretty contrived way of doing things. Ideally, everything should be a formcontrol or formgroup. That way you don’t have to wire up a lot of conditional code to do something simple like disabling a button . I would need to see more code to help any further I’m afraid.